# Recursion and TreeNode xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am newly introdused to xslt, I am doing kind of small tasks to familiarise myself with xslt. but I stuck in a problem which I could not solve in transforming a xml file into another one.
The scenario:
The input is a xml file contains nodes, each one is a pair of son and father tags which indicates the name of the current node by the tag , and the name of the father node by tag < father >.
what I am trying to do is to generate a tree of node, the first node is the one that has no father (I created it manually with name 0 and level in tree 1), then looking for all nodes that have the father tag equals to (0) as a first step, I will get in my input file (1 and 4), here I create a new node into the node (0) holds the name (1) and has a level in tree equals to (2) then I will go and look for all nodes that have the father tag equals to (1) and so on, when I reach to the point where is no more children for (1), I will create another node with name (4) and has the same level in the tree as the node with name (1) then continue looking for nodes who have the father tag equals to (4) and so on.
I have this xml:

```
<TypedPolling xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling">
    <TypedPolling0>
        <TypedPolling0>
            <son>1</son>
            <father>0</father>
        </TypedPolling0>
        <TypedPolling0>
            <son>2</son>
            <father>1</father>
        </TypedPolling0>
        <TypedPolling0>
            <son>3</son>
            <father>0</father>
        </TypedPolling0>
        <TypedPolling0>
            <son>4</son>
            <father>3</father>
        </TypedPolling0>
    </TypedPolling0>
</TypedPolling>
```

the previous xml file should be transformed into this xml file:

```
<ns0:TreeNode>
    <ns0:node>0</ns0:node>
    <ns0:LevelInTree>1</ns0:LevelInTree>
    <ns0:TreeNode>
      <ns0:node>1</ns0:node>
      <ns0:LevelInTree>2</ns0:LevelInTree>
      <ns0:TreeNode>
        <ns0:node>2</ns0:node>
        <ns0:LevelInTree>3</ns0:LevelInTree>
      </ns0:TreeNode>
    </ns0:TreeNode>
    <ns0:TreeNode>
        <ns0:node>3</ns0:node>
        <ns0:LevelInTree>2</ns0:LevelInTree>
        <TreeNode>
            <ns0:node>4</ns0:node>
            <ns0:LevelInTree>3</ns0:LevelInTree>
        </TreeNode>
    </TreeNode>
</TreeNode>
```

The code I write for to transform the input is (I used key element to get the sons who have a specified father name):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
            xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
            xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling"
            xmlns:ns0="http://NO.Aditro.Schemas.Organization.OrganizationTrees"
            xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp"
            exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 userCSharp">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" />
<xsl:key name="KeyItemFather" match="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPolling0/s0:TypedPolling0" use="@father" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="son" select="0" />
    <xsl:variable name="level" select="1" />
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="NewNode" select="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPolling0">
      <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="NewTreeNode" match="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPolling0/s0:TypedPolling0" mode="NewNode">
<xsl:param name="son" />
<xsl:param name="level" />
    <ns0:TreeNode>
      <ns0:node>
        <xsl:value-of select="$son" />
      </ns0:node>
      <ns0:LevelInTree>
        <xsl:value-of select="$level" />
      </ns0:LevelInTree>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('KeyItemFather', $son)" mode="NewNode">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ns0:TreeNode>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem I got is during the recursion something wrong happens that the recursion keeps going endlessly and `<ns0:node></ns0:node>` stays empty (it should be for example `<ns0:node>3</ns0:node>`). I can't find where is my mistake! :(

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your question and add information about the *exact* problem you're having - do you get an error message? If yes, what error message? Does the output you're getting differ from the expected output? If yes, how?

Comment: Please explain the logic of the required transformation. -- Note also that the output you show us has an undefined prefix.

Comment: @michael.hor257k According to what I understood from your question, the transformation I do is all about to transform a xml file which has nodes contain <son></son> < father ></father> to a tree of nodes and each node has a level indicates how far it is from the first node. Please correct me if I got your question incorrectly  !

Comment: The important part is that I get your question correctly. At this point I have no idea what you're trying to do. Please edit your question and explain how exactly I would arrive at the shown output if I were doing this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
                xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling"
                xmlns:ns0="http://NO.Aditro.Schemas.Organization.OrganizationTrees"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" indent="yes" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="FirstNodeSon" select="0" />
        <xsl:variable name="FirstNodelevel" select="1" />
        <ns0:TreeNode>
          <ns0:node>
            <xsl:value-of select="$FirstNodeSon"/>
          </ns0:node>
          <ns0:LevelInTree>
            <xsl:value-of select="$FirstNodelevel"/>
          </ns0:LevelInTree>
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="NewNode" select="s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPolling0/s0:TypedPolling0[s0:father=$FirstNodeSon]">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$FirstNodelevel+1" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </ns0:TreeNode>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template name="NewTreeNode" match="s0:TypedPolling0" mode="NewNode">
    <xsl:param name="level" />
    <xsl:variable name="CurrentNodeSon" select="s0:Son" />
    <ns0:TreeNode>
      <ns0:node>
        <xsl:value-of select="s0:Son" />
      </ns0:node>
      <ns0:LevelInTree>
        <xsl:value-of select="$level" />
      </ns0:LevelInTree>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:TypedPolling/s0:TypedPolling0/s0:TypedPolling0[s0:father=$CurrentNodeSon]" mode="NewNode">
        <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ns0:TreeNode>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your use of `mode` is unnecessary and confusing. OTOH, you *should* be using a `key` to get the child nodes - as you have started in your OP. -- P.S. I believe that if you fix that and remove all the redundant variables and namespace declarations, you will arrive at the answer I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you're pretty close: the design approach is certainly right. There could be errors in things you haven't shown us, like the namespace declarations - it's useful to show a complete runnable stylesheet, so we can try it ourselves and use our favourite debugging tools, without having to fill in the bits you left out.

The thing I find confusing is that your source data starts with one TypedPolling start tag followed by three TypedPolling0 start tags. The first two of these start tags have no corresponding end tag. Assuming you just left those out, your `father` elements are four levels deep. So your `xsl:key` declaration is wrong on two counts: firstly it matches `father` attributes rather than elements (`use="@father"`), and secondly it has too few ancestor levels. Note that you don't actually need to specify a full path here, it would be quite enough to say

```
<xsl:key name="KeyItemFather" match="s0:TypedPolling0" use="father" />
```

The other thing I notice is that your template rule has two parameters but (in both calls) you are only supplying one. In fact, you don't need the `$son` parameter, because you can get that information by accessing `child::son` from the context node.

Comment: Dear Mr.Kay,
I have added the nameSpace and edited the source code, hope it became easier to be tested... thanks

Comment: OK, that means the `xsl:key/@match` is now correct, but the `@use` is still wrong, and there's still the problem that you declare the template with two parameters and only call it with one.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, you want to do something like this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:s0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling"
xmlns:ns0="http://NO.Aditro.Schemas.Organization.OrganizationTrees"
exclude-result-prefixes="s0">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="s0:TypedPolling0" use="s0:father" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- create root node -->
    <ns0:TreeNode>
        <ns0:node>0</ns0:node>
        <ns0:LevelInTree>1</ns0:LevelInTree>
        <!-- get top-level nodes -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', 0)">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="2" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ns0:TreeNode>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="s0:TypedPolling0">
    <xsl:param name="level"/>
    <ns0:TreeNode>
        <ns0:node>
            <xsl:value-of select="s0:son" />
        </ns0:node>
        <ns0:LevelInTree>
            <xsl:value-of select="$level" />
        </ns0:LevelInTree>
        <!-- get children -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', s0:son)">
            <xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ns0:TreeNode>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:TreeNode xmlns:ns0="http://NO.Aditro.Schemas.Organization.OrganizationTrees">
   <ns0:node>0</ns0:node>
   <ns0:LevelInTree>1</ns0:LevelInTree>
   <ns0:TreeNode>
      <ns0:node>1</ns0:node>
      <ns0:LevelInTree>2</ns0:LevelInTree>
      <ns0:TreeNode>
         <ns0:node>2</ns0:node>
         <ns0:LevelInTree>3</ns0:LevelInTree>
      </ns0:TreeNode>
   </ns0:TreeNode>
   <ns0:TreeNode>
      <ns0:node>3</ns0:node>
      <ns0:LevelInTree>2</ns0:LevelInTree>
      <ns0:TreeNode>
         <ns0:node>4</ns0:node>
         <ns0:LevelInTree>3</ns0:LevelInTree>
      </ns0:TreeNode>
   </ns0:TreeNode>
</ns0:TreeNode>
```